# Remove additional files when deploying to a azure web application

Tags: visual-studio-code

When deploying to an azure web app from Visual Studio Code is it then possible to  remove additional files like you can do in Visual Studio?

Comment: Thomas, were you able to solve this problem? I'm running into it right now.

Comment: Nopes. I ended up using kudu and dit it manually through the cmd. Sorry :(